# My site opens in quirks mode how to fix it?

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode

Hey Guys Here is the URL of my website http://www.avmsolutionsuk.com/ thats opening in Quirks mode in IE... Please help me to fix this....

Comment: The doctype has to be the first thing on the page, don't have a commented out HTML5 doctype. Also get rid of the tab or spaces in front of that doctype as well.

Comment: have you checked given URL ???

Comment: Yes, and you have this first `[tab here]<!--<!doctype html>-->` which is, as I stated before, _wrong_. You also do not have `<head>` anywhere? You can also try adding this meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` instead of that IE9 one.

Comment: @TheZ i have done as guided by you in previous comment . please check url http://www.avmsolutionsuk.com/ but still its not working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

in head